# Get cell value from Outlook/Exchange address book into Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, exchange, address-book

There is a document for use in an employee performance review. A manager and employee are named on the form.

I have used a drop-down list to select a name and =VLOOKUP() to get the email address and telephone number from a table in the workbook.

```
MANAGER     Suzie Smith     suzie@company.com   +1 202 555 1212
EMPLOYEE    Joe Smith       joe@company.com     +1 202 555 1213
```

What I really want is a way to popup the Outlook address book for each person to be selected. The name, email, and telephone number cell would populate from the address book entry.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Have you tried Data > Get Data > From Other Sources > From Microsoft Exchange?

Comment: @gns100, I would like to try that, but I do not find `From Microsoft Exchange` as a data source. Is this something that needs to be installed?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, the option to get data from Exchange requires the M365 for enterprise subscriptions, see [this link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/get-data-from-microsoft-exchange-in-excel/c36659b3-7348-40ea-af76-2b7baf15d682). And for instructions to retrieve data from Exchange to Excel, you can refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/microsoft-exchange.

However, per my understanding, this still cannot meet your requirement to popup the Outlook address book for each person to be select in the cell and then auto populate the other entries.

As far as I know, there's no other native feature which can be used for this either. So personally I'd suggest just using your current method or you can looking for methods involving development like using VBA scripts.

Comment: Thank you for your message, @Yuki Sun. I think you have found what I have found. I will leave the question open for now to see if someone else suggests a way. If no one does, I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: You're welcome : )  It would be nice to know if someone else can come up with a better way for this.